# Interpreting the meaning of Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I am reading an introductory course on [calculus](https://books.google.com/books?id=fSoJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA81&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false). In chapter 2, the author presents the following example:

> Find the vertical asymptotes of $f(x)=\tan(x)$.

The proposed solution goes like this:

[image]

My question is what is meant by the following:

$\cos(x) \rightarrow 0^+$ as $x \to (\pi/2)^-$

My interpretation is as follows:

The value of $\cos(x)$ approaches $0$ from right as the value of $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ from the left.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes this is the correct interpretation.

Comment: absolutely  correct!

Comment: @PeterForeman thanks